# How to load people as typing using office fabric and microsoft graph API

Tags: reactjs, microsoft-graph-api, peoplepicker

How to use office fabric react people picker using Microsoft Graph API? I have to search entire Azure active directory to show the results in people picker?https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users this url fetches only top 100 users but how can I call API to load users as I type the characters?

Answer (score 0):

The users endpoint can take OData search parameters to help you narrow your results. Like this:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=Department eq 'Engineering'
```

[List users graph documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0)

The users endpoint supports paging so if you have more results you can get the next page using the nextLink that you will get in the response. It looks like this:

```
"@odata.nextLink": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$top=5&$skiptoken=X%274453707 ... 6633B900000000000000000000%27"
```

Using the nextLink value in your next query to the graph will let you get the next page of users. You add it using the skiptoken url parameter like this:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$skiptoken=X%274453707 ... 6633B900000000000000000000%27
```

All of this is documented in the graph documentation on graph.microsoft.com.